# (Proof-verification) Prove that a consistent linear system Ax = b has infinitely many solutions if and only if Ax = 0 has a nontrivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Prove that a consistent linear system $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions if and only if $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution. 
(Note: A is a homogenous matrix)

In order to prove this, we have to prove two separate statements, namely:

1) If $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions, $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution.
2) If $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution, $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions.

**Proof of statement 1:**
Since $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions, there are at least two distinct solutions, say $y_1$ and $y_2$, where $y_1 ≠ y_2$.

So $Ay_1 = b$ and $Ay_2 = b.$

Then, $A(y_1 – y_2) = Ay_1 – Ay_2 = b – b = 0.$
So $y_1 – y_2 ≠ 0$ is a nontrivial solution to $Ax = 0.$

**Proof of statement 2:**
If $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution $y$, then $Ay = 0$, where $y≠0$.
If $Ax = b$, then
$A(y+x) = Ay + Ax = 0 + b = b$
According to the uniqueness theorem, $A(αy) = 0$ for any scalar $α$ if $A(y) = 0.$
Therefore, $A(αy + x) = A(αy) + Ax = 0 + Ax = b$ for any scalar $α$
So if $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution, $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions.

Proof by contradiction:
If $Ax = 0$ has a trivial solution $y$, then $Ay = 0.$
Also, if $Ax = b$, then $A(y + x) = Ay + Ax = 0 + b = b.$
According to the uniqueness theorem, $A(αy) = 0$ for any scalar $α$ if $A(y) = 0.$
However, if $y = 0$, then $αy = 0$ for any scalar $α$, which implies that there is only one solution, not infinitely many.

---

Could someone verify my proof and see if I have worded anything incorrectly or missed anything?

Comment: Not very clear. $x$, $y$, $b$ live where?

Comment: A is a  matrix and this is a linear system of equarions.

Comment: I've understood that;o)  But… is $A$ a square matrix?

Comment: A is a homogeneous matrix.

Comment: What is a homogeneous matrix?

Comment: A system of linear equations is homogeneous if all of the constant terms are zero: A homogeneous system is equivalent to a matrix equation of the form. where A is an m × n matrix, x is a column vector with n entries, and 0 is the zero vector with m entries.

Comment: At last, I have the details I wanted: $A$ is an $m{\times}n$ matrix, and it corresponds to a system of $m$ linear equations with $n$ unknowns! B.t.w. it is meaningless to say a matrix is homogebeous.

Comment: Is the proof by contradiction only for statement 2? Also, the negation of ‘$Ax$ has a non-trivial solution’ is *not* ‘$Ax=0$ has a trivial solution’.

Comment: Yeah the proof of contradiction is only for the second statement. And is the negation 'has no solutions' then?

Comment: And also, is a proof of contradiction even needed to proof the second statement?